# How to Pass MySQL null parameter on DbCommand in Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, enterprise-library

I'm trying to pass a null value for the first parameter in the code below, but MySQL complains that

```
Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE myProc; expected 2, got 1
```

When I manually call the procedure with the first argument as null, it works, but when `EmptyAsNullStartsWith(employeeNumberText.Text)` returns null, it complains.

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbType"]
);
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("staff_listforinquiry");
db.AddeParameter(
  cmd, 
  "in_employeeNumber", 
  DbType.String, 
  EmptyAsNullStartsWith(employeeNumberText.Text)
);
db.AddeParameter(
  cmd, 
  "in_name", 
  DbType.String, 
  EmptyAsNullContains(employeeNameText.Text)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try having EmptyAsNullContains(employeeNameText.Text) return DBNull instead of regular null?

Comment: It now works, with just a standard null.  I suspect something was being cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(employeeNumberText.Text != "")
      db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "in_employeeNumber", DbType.String, employeeNumberText.Text);
else
      db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "in_employeeNumber", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```